# Correct way to add and remove classes to buttons in React / Typescript - Button group

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a storybook component used in my project and I want to create a button group which takes one of those buttons and when clicked adds an active class but when another button with same class is clicked it disables the other one so its only one button with an active class, this is for a button group. So far I can get it to work with one button but if I add more then the active class still appears on the others.

Code so far:

**Original storybook component**

```
import React from 'react';
import './Button.scss';

interface ButtonProps {
    children: React.ReactNode;
    onClick?: (event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement>) => void;
    variant: string | string;
    className?: string | string;
}

const Button: React.FunctionComponent<ButtonProps> = (props: ButtonProps) => {
    return (
        <button type="button" onClick={props.onClick} className={`btn-${props.variant}`}>{props.children}</button>
    )
}

export default Button;
```

**Other component**

```
const ActiveBtn: React.FunctionComponent = () => {

    const [active, setActive] = React.useState<boolean>(true)
    const handleClick = () => {
        alert()
        setActive(toggle => !toggle)}
    return (
        <>
        <Button variant={active ? 'tertiary' : 'tertiary-active'} onClick={handleClick}>{active ? '.Active' : 'Active'}</Button>
        </>
    )
}
```

used in the component via

```
<ActiveBtn />
```

Comment: How are you rendering the button as a button group ?

Comment: did you try to create a parent component that has a state for activeBtn which has the button number and this component has 4 or 5 buttons, then you render the Button or ActiveBtn depending on the state value?

Comment: So to render the button group, I know this is not correct but I am just adding the component <ActiveBtn /> 3 times, which is not correct or ideal

Comment: @WaleedJubeh No, can you eloborate on that approach?